# ¿Qué es el tapjacking? Android

Tags: android, seguridad

Buenas a todos, resulta que estoy trabajando con un `framework` de Android que tiene un término que acabo de descubrir por primera vez, el `TapJacking`. Por lo que he podido leer de la documentación del `framework`, este provee ciertos métodos para evitar que aplicaciones "`filter`" puedan hacer uso del `tapjacking`. Pero no me queda muy claro de que se trata todo esto y me parece interesante.

¿Alguien podría aclararme un poco más de que se trata?

Comment: Que framework es Fabio?, si tienes mayor a OS 4.0.3 no debe ser problema.

Comment: Es un framework de propio de un cliente. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `TapJacking` es una practica que te permite capturas los toques de una actividad, pero enviando los toques a otra actividad subyacente.

Básicamente, cuando tu tocas un botón en tu pantalla en `activity`, es posible que lo que estés tocando, no sea lo que ves, si no una actividad oculta.

Esto se podría usar para crear aplicaciones maliciosas o hacerte descargar cosas sin tu consentimiento.

Fuente: [WeLiveSecurity](https://www.welivesecurity.com/la-es/2015/07/01/tapjacking-enganos-android/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de ayuda.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos :)

Comment: Las aplicaciones maliciosas son las que tienen implementado obtener información mediante "tapjacking". En cuanto a "podrían hacerte descargar cosas sin tu consentimiento", esto no aplica, lo que se tiene que evitar es no descargar aplicaciones que no conozcamos y revisar los permisos..

Answer (score 0):

`TapJacking` (similar a [ClickJacking](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) en web),  ocurre cuando una aplicación maliciosa muestra una interfaz de usuario falsa que parece que se puede interactuar con ella, pero en realidad pasa eventos de interacción como tocar con el dedo a una interfaz de usuario oculta detrás de ella para uso que podría ser malicioso.

**En pocas palabras otro programa malicioso intercepta los eventos táctiles y lo peligroso es que podrían ser interceptados datos sensibles como son contraseñas o datos privados del usuario.**

Sin embargo esto se corrigió en versiones de sistema operativo posteriores a android 4.0.3, si aún cuentas con un dispositivo de esta versión o anterior, debes tomar como consideraciones, revisar los permisos de las aplicaciones que instalas y no esta de más tener instalado un antivirus.

Comment: Interesante información, muchas gracias.